# What is the best way to handle user profiles in a database?

Tags: database, settings

Almost every web application now allows you to setup a basic profile (Even Stack Exchange does). The question is how should you be storing the data in your database?

Should you just add more columns to your **users** database table, or should you setup another table called **user_profiles** that has a foreign key of user_id?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? SQL or NoSQL?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite subjective:

## Separate table

- easier to fetch user without profile
- when some user doesn't have a profile (one-to-one optional relationship), you don't pay anything in terms of storage
- sharing profile (?!?) - can't imagine such a scenario, but...

## Single table

- no JOINs required when loading
- related information in one place
- strong one-to-one (typically every user will have a profile, maybe created implicitly) relationships tend to be merged to single table